# 'uninitialized constant Bundler' from Bash command

Tags: ruby, bash

I am creating a bash ".command" file to allow co-workers to more easily kick off a Ruby script I wrote. Here is what it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "$0")"
ruby my_script.rb
```

When the command runs, it generates the following error:

```
my_script.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
```

If I run `ruby my_script.rb` directly from Terminal, all is fine. Additionally, I have confirmed that the bash script is using the correct version of Ruby and RubyGems. I can even run `bundle install` correctly from the script. Given all of the dependencies seems to be available to the bash script, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here are the first few lines of `my_script.rb`:

```
Bundler.require
require "json"
require "fileutils"
require "open-uri"
```

Comment: What is the content of `my_script.rb`, and more specifically, at line 1?

Comment: I added the first few lines above :)

Comment: add `require "bundler"` before `Bundle.require`?